# Using haml or erb code in ModalBox causes afterLoad callback to not get called

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, modal-dialog

I open a ModalBox with:

```
=link_to_function "Add", "Modalbox.show('appt', {title: this.title, width: 600, height: 400, afterLoad: function() { alert('Content loaded') } });"
```

This loads a haml file. When the haml file contains certain code, the callback never gets triggered. The same actually happens with .erb files as well.

For example, the callback gets triggered when the file contains:

```
<% form_for(:appointment) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
<% end %>
```

but not when it contains:

```
<% form_for(:appointment) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  <%= f.submit 'Update' %>
<% end %>
```

Any clues?

**EDIT:**

I narrowed it down and it breaks on this code in modal.js:

```
var firstEl = this.focusableElements.find(function findFirst(el){
  i++;
  return el.tabIndex == 1;
}) || this.focusableElements.first();
```

Haven't really looked into why, but since it's just trying to set focus on the first found element I'm just commenting out the line 'this._setFocus();' in '_putContent'.

I'm still curious why that breaks in the case mentioned above in case anyone knows.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and your post was very helpful!
What I also find out is that line 361 causes error.
I modify it to be: 
`"if (firstEl) firstEl.focus();"`

Now IE8 gives an error message with a little explanation:
*"Error: Can't move focus to the control because it is invisible, not enabled, or of a type that does not accept the focus."*

Probably IE cannot set focus to the element if it is not present on display. And my guess is that at the moment focus is being set element is indeed still hidden.
It seems FF handles that better though.

So for my workaround I commented line 361 and it seems working now.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just set up a tabIndex attribute to "1" for the first filed at the modal?

```
<% form_for(:appointment) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  <%= f.submit 'Update', :tabindex => 1 %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Sure, that would probably do the same thing as the code that's breaking, but I'm more just curious why that code is breaking. I don't like having to edit 3rd party code b/c if I ever go to update it and the bug still isn't fixed then I have to discover, remember, and refix the bug. Thanks though, yes, your idea is good for those that need a workaround for the focus issue.